# How do I stop all sounds, except some?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am creating an options menu for my game, where there is a mute button for sound effects and music. When the mute button for music is checked, all music should be muted throughout the entire game. When the mute button for the sound effects is checked, then all sound effects should be muted. Both can be checked, or only one can checked. If one is checked, then the other should work. I know I can use the SoundMixer.stopAll() function, but this isn't really what I am looking for. Could you please help on how I can build this code?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a SoundManager class that handles playing different sound effects / music each on a given SoundChannel and then group those SoundChannels by whatever criteria you have.

This SoundManager would also have a mute state for whatever groups you have, that you can check/set.

You could have a playSound method that checks that mute state to determine if it should actually play that sound/music.

So the basic concept is that all audio gets triggered through this class. If mute state is changed to true for sound effects then it will stop all sound effects currently playing.

How you group your audio is up to you. You could store each type in an array, so you can just iterate through it to stop all sounds of that type if mute is turned on.